# How to evaluate the production `SourceElements : SourceElements SourceElement` when parse tree only has one statement

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecmascript-5

Regarding EcmaScript specification 5.1, specifically, the semantic explanation for the `SourceElements` production is:

```
SourceElements : SourceElements SourceElement
```

(in clause 14.0)

The semantic explanation for the above production has me confused.

Let's assume you have two statements (call it `s1` and `s2`), then by the semantic explanation given by the above clause, I would set the result of `s1` to `headResult`. If it's not an abrupt completion, I then set the result of `s2` to `tailResult`. I either return the result with tailResult's value or headResult's value.

My question is, what do I do in the case when there's just one statement?

Do I just return the result of `s1`? Do I check it for an abrupt completion? What do I do with the value?

I guess I don't know how to translate the left recursion to the case when there's just one statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SourceElements` has two productions:

```
SourceElements:
    SourceElement
    SourceElements SourceElement
```

When there's only one statement in the program, it matches the first production. When there's more than one statement, it matches the second production, and recurses.

Comment: Beat me to the punch :)

Comment: Barmar, thanks for answering. But in the spec, it says that you treat the result of the left recursion one way, and treat the right non-termina

Comment: Try again, you got cut off.

Comment: Barmar, thanks for taking the time to answer. 

I guess I should clarify. In the spec, it tells you how to handle the second production, but not the first production.

What then, do I do when I only have one statement? The spec never says what should be done if the we match the first production.

Hope I explained it better.

Comment: Since they don't provide a detailed explanation for evaluating that production, you just return the result of evaluating `SourceElement`. And the productions for that are explained in the next two paragraphs.